# Orbital shift when i use atoms near it

Tags: overlays, chemfig, chemmacros

I'm drawing some orbitals and I noticed that when I have an atom near the orbital, the orbital shifts down a little (it's very ugly).

This happens only if I put the hydrogen at the beginning of the formula

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\chemsetup{modules=orbital}
\chemsetup[orbital]{overlay,opacity=.75}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{H-[:65]{\orbital{s}}-[:0]-[:65]H}
\end{document}
```

[image: orbital not aligned]

if you use

```
\chemfig{-[:65]{\orbital{s}}-[:0]-[:65]H}
```

the orbital is perfectly aligned.

[image: orbital aligned]

Comment: So, you created a command that draws a circle on the the coordinate in which is invoked... right?

Comment: Sorry, my example still wasn't minimal. This one's better: `\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{H-[:65]x-[:0]}
\chemfig{-[:65]x-[:0]}
\end{document}` (the horizontal bond is shifted with respect to the `x` – or probably rather the `x` is shifted. The same effect I guess)

Answer (score 7):

I am quite certain that this issue arises due to the vertical placement mechanism of the `chemfig` package.

Specifically, the `chemfig` manual (v1.2d, December 1, 2015, currently latest) specifically states that

> [...] the vertical placement of the arrival atom depends on the height of the departure atom. [...] ChemFig adds to each arrival atom the `\vphantom` of the departure atom [...]
>   (ch. III, sec. 4, p. 27)

This explains the differences of the two formula: In the first example, the first `H` passes its height to the following atom, causing the vertical shift. (notice the nonzero height of the red-colored `fbox` on the 
left orbital atom)

[image: demo image]

To fix this, `chemfig` provides the `\chemskipalign` macro, which disables the alignment mechanism and allows the orbital to align correctly, like on the right molecule (see also ch. III, sec. 4, pp. 27/28):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{xcolor} % colors for fboxes
\chemsetup{modules=orbital}
\chemsetup[orbital]{overlay,opacity=.75}

\begin{document}
    \fboxsep=0pt % fboxes
    \renewcommand*\printatom[1] % fboxes
    {\color{red}\fbox{\color{black}\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}}} % fboxes
    \chemfig{H-[:65]{\orbital{s}}-[:0]-[:65]H} % bad
    \quad
    \chemfig{-[:65]{\orbital{s}}-[:0]-[:65]H}
    \quad
    \chemfig{H-[:65]\chemskipalign{\orbital{s}}-[:0]-[:65]H} % good, added \chemskipalign
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, it works, but what if I want to write something _inside_ the orbital? (it was my first intention)

Comment: Use this (see picture below):  \chemfig{H-[:65,,,,,shorten >=4pt]({\orbital{s}})(H)-[:0,,,,,shorten <=3pt]-[:65]H}

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\chemsetup{modules=orbital}
\chemsetup[orbital]{overlay,opacity=.75}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{H-[:65]({\orbital{s}})-[:0]-[:65]H}
\end{document}
```

I put the "{\orbital{s}" into a ( )

[image]

to have more "control" of the bonds, and to put "something" into the orbital, try:

```
....
\chemfig{H-[:65,,,,,shorten >=4pt]({\orbital{s}})(H)-[:0,,,,,shorten <=3pt]-[:65]H}
.....
```

[image]